# Computing information taken out from applying 'aggregate' in R

Tags: r, aggregate, usage-statistics

I have the following information:

`head(Callao20)`

```
  Dia Mes  Aho Temp
1  12 Feb 2020   NA
2  12 Feb 2020   NA
3  12 Feb 2020   NA
4  12 Feb 2020   NA
5  12 Feb 2020   NA
6  12 Feb 2020   NA
```

Despite the fact that I have NA's, I also have further information below. By the way, do you recommend me to delete such NA's?.

Anyway, I'd like to estimate the cv for each month, then I estimated the following parameters monthly:

```
aggregate(Callao20[, 4], list(Callao20$Mes), mean)
   Group.1        x
1      Feb       NA
2      Mar 17.84195
3      Abr 17.50487
4      May 16.77294
5      Jun 16.45750
6      Jul 15.53369
7      Ago 14.93071
8      Set 14.65176
9      Oct 14.60224
10     Nov 14.48786
11     Dic 14.47635
```

...and also:

```
aggregate(Callao20[, 4], list(Callao20$Mes), sd)
   Group.1         x
1      Feb        NA
2      Mar 0.6280132
3      Abr 0.7163050
4      May 0.3962204
5      Jun 0.4165841
6      Jul 0.3743657
7      Ago 0.4063140
8      Set 0.3538223
9      Oct 0.6060919
10     Nov 0.5034747
11     Dic 0.3035467
```

> Knowing that cv = (sd/mean)*100, **how do you recommend me to estimate it for each month, from what I already have?.**

Comment: *"recommend me to delete such NA's"* is a tough question to answer, as it depends very much on the context of the data and your reporting. For instance, there are times when `NA`s are *expected* and known to be not helpful, in which case removing them can be useful. However, many times I have found the mere presence of `NA` to be informative, even if I don't know why it has no number. In that case, removing it is deleting useful data (even if you don't know yet how to aggregate or use that missingness).

Answer (score 1):

We could use `tidyverse` as this can handle `NA` better

```
library(dplyr)
Callao20 %>%
     group_by(Mes) %>%
     summarise(out = sd(Temp, na.rm = TRUE)/mean(Temp, na.rm = TRUE) * 100)
```

---

Or if we want to use `aggregate`, we can use a formula approach (`R 4.1.0`)

```
aggregate(Temp ~ Mes, Callao20,
        \(x) sd(x, na.rm = TRUE)/mean(x, na.rm = TRUE) * 100)
```

Comment: `boxplot(Temp~Mes, data=Callao20)`
Please, how can I add the 'cv' in my graphic?
Thank you in advance for your answer!

Comment: @ДжиммиМартина You can do a `merge` with the `aggregate` data and use the new column (after renaming it) use that in boxplot

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to do this in one `aggregate` command instead of breaking it down in separate `aggregate` calls and then trying to combine them.

```
aggregate(Callao20[, 4], list(Callao20$Mes), 
          function(x) (sd(x, na.rm = TRUE)/mean(x, na.rm = TRUE))*100)
```

Comment: `boxplot(Temp~Mes, data=Callao20)`
Please, how can I add the 'cv' in my graphic?
Thank you in advance for your answer!